# Why not use Gmail's "Less Secure Apps" SMTP directly, instead of Mandrill/Mailgun/etc

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

Gmail lets you send emails from 3rd party via its SMTP settings if you enable "Less Secure Apps". Presumably you can use this for transactional emails, something you'd normally use services like Mandrill, Mailgun, SendGrid.

1. These services cost money
2. They have more complex setup than Gmail-direct (DKIM/SPF records, domain verification, etc)

Indeed, I setup a personal Discourse server via Gmail's "easy way" successfully, and a company's Discourse via SES "the hard way". Why *not* just use Gmail? "Less Secure" is obviously a yellow flag in that checkbox, but is it *that* much less secure if you're following good practice (hardening the server with the smtp.conf pointing to Gmail, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google would like you to upgrade to more modern methods of authentication (nowadays typically involving hardware tokens). Because an attacker is less likely to gain permanent control over such device - unlike a password, which only requires knowing it. For now, that is all they mean by that "less secure" yellow flag about passwords.

But **Google will simply not allow you to use their servers to relay [large volumes](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839) of mail**, unless you setup a service specifically meant for that purpose - freemail accounts certainly are not.

> "You have reached a limit for sending mail"
>
> You may see this message if you send an email to a total of more than
>   500 recipients in a single email and or more than 500 emails in a day
>   sent.

Because when Google allows you to send significant mail volume via their servers, they are exposing themselves to abuse. If a spammer sends mail through Google, other mail providers will be more careful about accepting mail originating from Google. As a mail account that cannot send mail to pretty much everyone is not a very good mail account - Google will impose some limitations to avoid risking devaluating their freemail service.

One of the email service providers you mentioned has so far *exclusively* sent me phishing mails and supplied a significant contribution to the respective spam filter training dataset. They do not have to be that careful about fighting abuse, because unlike Google they can pretend to their customers that it is *normal* to send a massive bunch of mails of which only a few reach the recipients INBOX. Others like me consider that to be closer to network abuse.

So yes, please, by all means stay away from companies that advertise their *"deliverability"* services - but do accept the fact that **sending mail requires some effort to prevent abuse, and that effort is going to cost some amount of money**, wherever you buy that service. Yes, even at [Google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491), who provide free email accounts. You will still have that cost if you roll your own servers, and probably a greater cost because these sort of tasks scale well and email providers like Google are very large.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I didn't know about the 500 msg cap, that blockquote is key